# Set adapter to use Windows Firewall Public Profile

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall

I'm configuring a server to provide VPN access to employees on the road. This server is virtualized, which means that both the Internal and the External network adapters, are actually connections to the internal network (they both use the same host NIC).

On the router, I'm configuring the External adapter's IP address as a DMZ host, so that all traffic would flow to this IP address. Since I'm doing that, I want to make sure that the windows Firewall is using the public profile on that network adapter, but right now it is using the Domain Profile.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The network determination algorithm performs the following analysis:

- If the computer is not a member of a domain, it is always attached to another network.
- If the last-received Group Policy update DNS name matches any of the connection-specific DNS suffixes of the currently connected connections on the computer that are not PPP or SLIP-based, then the computer is attached to a managed network.
- If the last-received Group Policy update DNS name does not match any of the connection-specific DNS suffixes of the currently connected connections on the computer that are not PPP or SLIP-based, then the computer is attached to another network.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878049.aspx

You cannot make a system use the public or standard profile if it is a member of a domain and it is currently connected to that domain and receiving GPO updates from that domain.